# This C code just get HTTP header, But not a html file

Tags: c, linux, http, sockets, network-programming

I wrote This code in Linux platform.

When this program was run, It was expect to print `HTTP header` and `html content`.
Just like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
...
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
</html>
```

But when I run it, I found it just print `HTTP header`

This is my C code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>  // for struct sockaddr_in AF_IN
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  // for inet_pton
#include <netinet/in.h> // for IPPROTO_TCP

#define PORT "80"
#define BAIDU_IP "119.75.217.56"
#define GET_INFO "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com:80\r\n\r\n"

int main()
{
    int sock_local;
    in_port_t port = atoi(PORT);
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    sock_local = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    assert(sock_local > 0);

    int retVal = -1;
    retVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, BAIDU_IP, &server.sin_addr.s_addr);
    assert(retVal == 1);

    if (connect(sock_local, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ssize_t nByte = send(sock_local, GET_INFO, strlen(GET_INFO), 0);
    if( nByte <= 0)
    {
        perror("send");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char BUF[BUFSIZ];
    size_t recived_len = 0;
    while ((recived_len = recv(sock_local, BUF, BUFSIZ-1, 0)) > 0)
    {
        int statu;
        BUF[recived_len] = '\0';
        printf("%s", BUF);
        statu = (recived_len==BUFSIZ-1) ? 0 : 1;
        if (statu) break;
    }
    if (recived_len < 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
    }

    close(sock_local);
    return 0;
}
```

Could you help to recive both `HTTP head` and 'html content'?

I don't know why it dosen't works.

====================== Solution =============================

I'm very glad to say, I found solution to this problem by myself.

I delete `if (statu) break;`, then it works as I expect!

Comment: BUFSIZ was defined as 8192. HTTP header has 387 byte

Comment: What do the printed headers look like?  Was an HTTP `200` response code returned, or was it another response code, maybe a 3xx redirection to another URL?

Comment: size_t is unsigned. The recv() and read() syscalls can return a -1 value on error, which will confuse your programs logic.

Comment: htons() wants an integer argument, and PORT is a string constant.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be right here:

```
statu = (recived_len==BUFSIZ-1) ? 0 : 1;
if (statu) break;
```

I don't know why you have included this code. It seems to exit the loop unless you filled the buffer completely on the previous read. What is your reason for doing this?

Delete those two lines of code, and it should work.

(Oh, and by the way, that's not how you spell "received".)